# Android Jelly Bean: icons in app suddenly washed out

Tags: android, image-scaling, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have a app with a dashboard with icons. The app only has drawable-hdpi folde with the icons.

When I start both the 4.0 and 4.1 emulator and launch my app from eclipse to both of them, the quality of the icons differ extremely! It's ugly on jellybean.

What is going on??

[image: ICS] [image: Jellybean]

**Partial Manifest**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="false"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false" >
    </supports-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: What's the density of your emulator? It appears to be upscaling low resolution images, so I would make the assumption that your 4.1 emulator is set to a dpi of 320 (xhdpi) and you should provide the images in a `drawable-xhdpi` folder.

Comment: Both emulators have abstract density of 240

Comment: The strange thing is, i don't have lower resolution files then hdpi. So I don't understand what it's scaling.

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Or a link to it on pastebin?

Comment: Added relevant stuff of manifest.

Comment: Try it without the `supports-screens` tag.

Comment: Hero, thats great! It worked by removing supports-screens tag!! Please add as answer to get the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `supports-screen` tag from your manifest (specifically, the `anyDensity` attribute). According to the documentation:

> android:anyDensity
>
> Indicates whether the application includes
>   resources to accommodate any screen density.  For applications that
>   support Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher, this is "true" by
>   default and **you should not set it "false" unless you're absolutely
>   certain that it's necessary for your application to work.** The only
>   time it might be necessary to disable this is if your app directly
>   manipulates bitmaps (see the Supporting Multiple Screens document for
>   more information).

I'm not sure *exactly* what's happening between 4.0 and 4.1 that would cause the difference, but for the most part setting the `anyDensity` tag is a bad idea outside of very specific circumstances. As long as you've provided default resources (e.g. in the non-specific `drawable` folder), you won't need to specify it.

Comment: Yes, I do however have somehow used that in my app to not include scaling for some generated custom views. Well, now I need to recode some stuff.

Comment: Gotcha. Well, if there are specific drawables that you just want to avoid scaling for, you can also create a `drawable-nodpi` folder for those graphics, and the system won't scale anything taken from there.